# How to do server-side render of create-react-app

Tags: firebase, redux, google-cloud-functions, create-react-app, server-side-rendering

I have a create-react-app with code-splitting and I want to do a server-side render of only the HOME and Features page for SEO reasons

I currently use firebase hosting to host the app, is there any way to do a server-side rendering of just the two specific pages? 
I use react-router, Does **not** use nextjs in the app.

I have used cra-firebase and it has issues in compiling.